# Reading android developer on bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, handler

```
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
```

So I am trying to implement data transfer by bluetooth and I've been reading the android developer website on bluetooth. There Is just one part I don't understand and it's the code posted above. I've looked at several other websites and no one seems to have a good explanation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Handler allows the Bluetooth connection thread to communicate with the main thread.  In this case it's sending the number of bytes read and the buffer containing the bytes that were read.  If you look in the main activity you should find a Handler.handleMessage that receives the message, which usually contains a switch with one of the cases being MESSAGE_READ.